# Generating XSD sheme for WAF with data restriction from WCF project

Tags: regex, wcf, soap

I am trying to generate a xsd schema for waf (web application firewall) to validate requests coming from user side before they reach the service as second line of defense.

In my web service i using DataAnnotations to strict the input and i looking for a way to reflect it in xsd files generated for the service.

For example i have following DataAnnotation

```
[DataMember]
[StringLength(50)]
[RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z]")]
```

But in XSD generated type those restrictions are absent.

I'am using VS2010, .NET 4.

Answer (score 0):

I think to use DataAnnotation for wcf, you should use something like [WCF Data Annotations](http://wcfdataannotations.codeplex.com/) and not direct DataAnnotation (introduced for asp pages)